# Remap output styles of predefined ranges with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math

## Context

I want a semantic command to typeset 'vectors' in a consistent way. Currently, I am using bold to denote them, in documents where the main math font is italic, so I would like vectors to use a bold italic math font.

My math typeface is Latin Modern Math, used with `unicode-math` and `lualatex`.

## Problem

I want to be able to mark digits as vectors (e.g. vector zero). However, digits in math mode are upright, so I would like vector digits to be bold upright. Bold italic could be acceptable, but Latin Modern Math has no bold italic digits, and falls back to the normal math font when asked for one.

## Failed attempt

I though I could simply use the features of `unicode-math` described in § 4.1.1 of the manual (p. 8 in my manual) so that 'bold italic digits' actually uses the bold upright font.
However the example below fails: the rightmost zero looks exactly like the leftmost one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={bfit/{num}->bfup/{num}}]
\renewcommand{\vec}{\symbfit}
\begin{document}
\(\forall \vec{v} \in \symbb{R}^{3}\), \(0 \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}\)
\end{document}
```

## Questions

Is it possible to set the math fonts so that bold upright digits are used when bold italic digits are requested, as I tried in the example above?

If not, is there another way to achieve bold italic letters and bold upright (or even bold italic) digits in math mode with the same command?

Comment: In your case it should be sufficient to use `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[bold-style=ISO]
\renewcommand{\vec}{\symbf}`

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Actually, all the style options of `unicode-math` are interesting. I am surprised I missed these while looking for an answer.
Although I am still curious to understand why my attempt at remapping failed, I will gratefully accept this if you post it as an answer.